# facebook how to display application notifications next to applications name in the left sidebar?

Tags: facebook, api

i was wondering how i can make my app display that notification number next to the apps name in the left sidebar on facebook.

i see many apps that want to let you know that something happened, they made a change or something and u can see a counter.

i just don't know how that works and i can't find anything on google.

Maybe i'm not looking for the right thing.

all help much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the dashboard API methods. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/dashboard.incrementCount/

As an FYI, Facebook is moving some (all?) of the dashboard methods to the new requests dialog. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/